# Java date format conversion - getting wrong month

Tags: java, date

I have a problem in converting the date in java, don't know where i am going wrong...

```
    String dateStr = "2011-12-15";
    String fromFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd";
    String toFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy";

    try {
        DateFormat fromFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(fromFormat);
        Date date = (Date) fromFormatter.parse(dateStr);

        DateFormat toformatter = new SimpleDateFormat(toFormat);
        String result = toformatter.format(date);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Input date is 2011-12-15 and I am expecting the result as "15 December 2011", but I get it as "15 January 2011"

where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your `fromFormat` uses minutes where it should use months.

```
String fromFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
```

Answer (score 6):

I think the **fromFormat** should be "yyyy-MM-dd".

Here is the format:

- m == Minute in Hour
- M == Month in Year

More: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 2):

Look at the javadoc of [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and look at what the `m` represents. Not months as you think but minutes.

Answer (score 2):

```
 String fromFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
```

Answer (score 2):

From format should be:

```
String fromFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

Answer (score 1):

`m` in `SimpleDateFormat` stands for minutes, while `M` stands for month. Thus your first format should be `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: One thing I like SO for is a that questions are answered so quickly. 3 new answers during 1 minute when I typed an answer, awesome!

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( "2011-12-15" )                            // Date-only, without time-of-day, without time zone.
.format(                                                   // Generate `String` representing value of this `LocalDate`. 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.LONG )  // How long or abbreviated?
                     .withLocale(                          // Locale used in localizing the string being generated.
                         new Locale( "en" , "IN" )         // English language, India cultural norms.
                     )                                     // Returns a `DateTimeFormatter` object.
)                                                          // Returns a `String` object.
```

> 15 December 2011

## java.time

While the [accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8770739/642706) is correct (uppercase `MM` for month), there is now a better approach. The troublesome old date-time classes are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Your input string is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. So no need to specify a formatting pattern for parsing.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2011-12-15" );  // Parses standard ISO 8601 format by default.
Locale l = new Locale( "en" , "IN" ) ;  // English in India.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.LONG )
                                       .withLocale( l );
String output = ld.format( f );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "ld.toString(): " + ld );
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
```

> ld.toString(): 2011-12-15
>
> output: 15 December 2011

See [live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/9b9JkP).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well this may not be your case but may help someone. In my case after conversion, day of month and month set 1. So whatever date is, after conversion i get 1 jan which is wrong.
         After struggling i found that in date format i have used `YYYY` instead of `yyyy`. When i changed all caps Y to y it works fine.