# How to get date in "mmm dd" format for nl_NL locale?

Tags: java, date, locale

I want to get date in jave for nl_NL locale

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(Pattern, new Locale("nl_NL"));
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
String expectedDate = df.format(calendar.getTime()).toLowerCase();
System.out.println("Date in PST Timezone : " + expectedDate);
return expectedDate;
```

I am not getting it in correct nl_NL format!

can someone please help me in this ?

Comment: does this answer your question? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770726/java-date-format-conversion-getting-wrong-month

Comment: `MonthDay.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd", Locale.forLanguageTag("nl-NL")))` just gave me `jul. 20` Is this what you were after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never use 2-4 character pseudo-zones such as `PST`, `CST`, or `IST`. These values are not standardized, and are not even unique!

[Real time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) are in the format of `Continent/ Region` such as `Africa/Tunis` or `Asia/Tokyo`. For the time zone of most of the west coast of US, if that is what you meant by `PST`, use `America/Los_Angeles`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ;
```

Never use the terrible legacy date-time classes such as `Calendar`. Use only *java.time* classes.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Generate text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format wisely extended by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.

```
String output = zdt.toString() ;
```

Localize a textual representation for Dutch language and Netherlands culture.

```
Locale locale = new Locale( "nl" , "NL" ) ;
DateTimeFormatter f = 
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )
    .withLocale( locale ) 
;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/vHO9rW).

> 2020-07-17T09:30:58.183568-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]

> vrijdag 17 juli 2020 om 09:30:58 Pacific-zomertijd

Search to learn more. All this has been addressed many many times already on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not getting it in correct nl_NL format

That is because `new Locale("nl_NL")` is wrong. It must be either [**`new Locale("nl", "NL")`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#Locale-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) with separate `language` and `country` parameters, or [**`Locale.forLanguageTag("nl-NL")`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#forLanguageTag-java.lang.String-) with a `languageTag` parameter using a dash in the value. It is never with an underscore.

It is also because date pattern `"mmm dd"` is wrong. It must be [**`"MMM dd"`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216767/5221149) with M's in uppercase to represent *month*, not in lowercase which represents *minute*.

And finally, using time zone `PST` is wrong, because it is not well-defined. It can mean "Pitcairn Standard Time" or "Pacific Standard Time", and even that second one is wrong, because the US Pacific coast is currently observing `PDT` (Pacific Daylight Time). The correct time zone is `America/Los_Angeles`.

Applying those fixes to the question code:

```java
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd", new Locale("nl", "NL"));
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
String expectedDate = df.format(calendar.getTime()).toLowerCase();
System.out.println("Date in PST Timezone : " + expectedDate);
```

*Output*

```
Date in PST Timezone : jul. 17
```

Of course, for a date-only value, time zone doesn't really apply, but there it is.

---

You should however use the newer Java 8 Time API.

```java
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd", new Locale("nl", "NL"));
String date = MonthDay.now(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")).format(fmt);
System.out.println("Date : " + date);
```

*Output*

```
Date : jul. 17
```

You can also use `LocaleDate.now(...)`.